# Views with contextual filter ignores sort order and number of nodes per page

Tags: views

On my site I want to define tutorials. One tutorial consists of several nodes of the same **Tutorial content type**. The content type has a field **taxonomy term reference** and a weight, to determine the sort order.

My idea was to have a single view, selecting on **Tutorial content type**, ordering by weight, one node per page. So far this works. But to only show nodes for one specific **tutorial** I defined a contextual filter, on the tutorial field. Now only nodes for that specific tutorial are shown, as expected, but this also has the effect that:

- The nodes are no longer sorted by weight.
- I no longer have one node per page

I've been looking for workarounds, different settings, etc., so far to no available , so help would be greatly appreciated.

If this is a behavior of views that can't be helped, any other approaches to my use case would also be met with immediate gratitude.

Using: Drupal 7.39, Views 7.x-3.11

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example (with Drupal 7.39 and Views 7.x.3.11) and was not able to reproduce the issue. In short, I followed the following steps:

- Created a taxonomy vocabulary, called "**Tutorial Vocabulary**"
- Created a content type, called "**Tutorial Type**" containing two additional fields:

  1. "**Tutorial term**" (Entity Reference to Taxonomy Terms of type "Tutorial Vocabulary") and
  2. "**Weight**" (Integer).
- Created some content.
- Created a **View** for "Content" type "**Tutorial type**", added the "sorted by Weight" criterium, removed the default "**sorted by creation date**" criterium, and configured the default pager to display only "1 item"
- Created a **contextual filter** for the "**Tutorial term**" field, specifying "Show page not found" when the filter value is not in the URL, and leaving everything by default.

The **contextual filter** seems to work as expected when I pass the **tid** of the taxonomy terms: Only the nodes associated to a term are displayed, they are sorted by weight, and only one node per page.

Maybe you are following different steps from the ones I am listing above. If so, please edit your post to specify them, it might be useful in order to find a solution to your question.

Comment: Hi dinopmi, I'd like to thank you for your help in resolving this issue for me. I followed your steps and recreated everything in parallel to what I already had, and it worked. I then set about trying to find out why my old solution didn't. After some experimenting it finally hit me. My view and my vocabulary had the same name. So when I wanted to see my tutorial view (tutorial/tutorial1) I, in fact, got everything on taxonomy term tutorial/tutorial1, but didn't realize this.

Comment: Hi tassaert.l Glad of having been of any help!